# udp client server program communication to ibm bluemix containers

Tags: sockets, docker, udp, containers, ibm-cloud

I am newbie to bluemix containers. I have created a bluemix container and exposed the port 5005 for udp client server communication. The port was not able to receive message from my program from the host.

Below is my Docker file I created.

```
 FROM registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty:latest
 COPY pythonServer.py /home/
 EXPOSE 9080 5005/udp
 # Run Liberty via the supervisor
 CMD ["/root/bin/run_supervisor"]
```

My python Udp server program:

```python
import SocketServer

class MyUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    This class works similar to the TCP handler class, except that
    self.request consists of a pair of data and client socket, and since
    there is no connection the client address must be given explicitly
    when sending data back via sendto().
    """

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print data
        socket.sendto(data.upper(), self.client_address)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 5005
    server = SocketServer.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler)

    server.serve_forever()
```

My python udp client program

```python
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "134.168.20.209", 5005
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

# SOCK_DGRAM is the socket type to use for UDP sockets
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# As you can see, there is no connect() call; UDP has no connections.
# Instead, data is directly sent to the recipient via sendto().

while 1:
    data = raw_input("Enter something: ")
    print "you entered ", data
    sock.sendto(data , (HOST, PORT))
    received = sock.recv(1024)
    print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
    print "Received: {}".format(received)
```

I also exposed the port 5005, but it is still not able to communicate with the client program. Any problem on why the ports are not getting exposed in bluemix containers?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons there is a limited set of ports opened that can be accessed externally. UDP/TCP port 5005 is currently not included in this set. Actually no UDP ports are exposed now.

I suggest you to open a support ticket with the Bluemix support team and request this port to be opened.

ibm.biz/bluemixsupport

Comment: Is this true for both container groups and single containers? I was under the impression it was only an issue for container groups.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere what ports and protocols are supported?

Comment: this is valid for single containers. Due to security reasons there is no documentation for opened ports.